# No type was found that matches the controller named 'Hello'

Tags: vb.net, api, asp.net-web-api

I have registered a webhook with URL http://xxxxx.com/api/hello

Route configured is :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name:="MS_WebHookReceiverSecret_Custom",
routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
)
```

But I am getting the error: 
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://xxxxx.com/api/Hello'.

Comment: Any comments here will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have called the initialize functions after configuring the route as follows:

```
config.InitializeCustomWebHooks();
config.InitializeCustomWebHooksAzureStorage();
config.InitializeCustomWebHooksApis();
```